# Comes navigation drawer over actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation drawer of supported library.I am using latest material design layout.please someone answer.

> Blockquote

MainLayout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/primaryColorDark"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu" />
```

Comment: what is your problem post full xml and describe the problem

Comment: Navigation drawer comes over actionbar

Comment: I want it below actionbar.

Comment: show your activity layout full are you using toolbar for setting actionbar

Comment: <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/primaryColorDark"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

Comment: You should not post the code in comment

Comment: Reorder your  Views  in Layout File.that may solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Take a LinearLayout and put your toolbar first and below toolbar put your drawer.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        .
        .
        >
        <Toolbar .../>
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.....>
        <FrameLayout ..../> <!-- For holding fragments -->
    <navigationview../>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of navigation drawer. Use toolbar instead of old actionbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray93"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">
    <!-- Main activity home page -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Toolbar layout -->
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I use toolbar not actionbar.

Comment: My layout is same as this layout

Comment: Then please post your whole layout. as well as your styles.xml